# LED of pin 13 in Arduino Uno always on even if there is no program uploaded to it

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, led

I have purchased a brand new Arduino Uno today. While it was connected to the PC, the LED (pin 13) was always remaining on. I have uploaded a blank program, but the LED doesn't go off.

Help me with this issue, please. I am in a fix about it.

Comment: Have you tried to turn it off?

Comment: Ya..if I write a program to turn off..it turns off.but again if any blank code is uploaded..the led remains on

Answer (score 0):

The Arduino does not remember any states which have been set before a new program start. Without setting the digital port 13 the LED is turned on. You can set the port 13 by program (using it as output port) or you pull down the port by connecting it to ground (using it as input port).

Also see [tutorial about digital pins on the Arduino website](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins).

Comment: Thanks..but is there any way to rewrite it's firmware or install the firmware back?

Comment: @Kaiser You want to turn off the LED by firmware? Why?

Comment: because..when I first bought this arduino, pin 13 led didn&#39;t lit without any program , I mean while  the arduino run on blank program,  pin13 did not lit, and it was default setting

Comment: @Kaiser Digital ports are input ports after a system start. The state of an open input port is undefined without a pull up or pull down resistor. To switch off the LED set the output port to low or pull down the digital port when using it as input port.

Answer (score 0):

```
void setup() {
pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
}
```